# Editing a Form in Visual Studio when TFS is offline

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, tfs

I'm running Visual Studio 2010 and using Team Foundation Server, and this thing is pissing me off no end.

Here's the scenario: since I work from home it often happens to me to work at strange hours or on the week-end, when our TFS is offline. This has never been a problem, since usually I just reload the solution and when VS detects that the TFS is not available it promprts you to work offline.

Now, I usually work on WPF projects, and working offline has never be a problem, even when editing XAML files it works with no issues. But now I have to edit a Form from a Windows Forms project, and VS refuses to collaborate. Whatever I do to the form, VS just does nothing other than playing that obnoxious "bing" sound that usually plays when an error of some kind occours. It doesn't even popup an error dialog box, just does nothing!

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok figured it out, I had to remove the "Read Only" attribute from ALL the files in the project (I had tried with the project file and form file, but that isn't enough evidently).